# Definition of $(\exists_1x)\mathscr B(x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , page 99 about the definition of $(\exists_1x)\mathscr B(x)$. In the book , the definition is written like this:

> $(\exists_1x)\mathscr B(x)$ as for $$(\exists x)\mathscr B(x) \land (\forall x)(\forall y)(\mathscr B(x) \land \mathscr B(y) \to x = y)$$
> In this definition, the new variable $y$ is assumed to be the first variable that
> does not occur in $\mathscr B(x)$. A similar convention is to be made in all other
> definitions where new variables are introduced.

My question is , what do they exactly mean by "*...assumed to be the first variable...*" ?

Comment: In the formal definition of the language the variables are enumerated: $x_1,x_2,\ldots$. Thus, if $x_n$ is the last variable occurring into the formula, $y$ will be $x_{n+1}$. That's all

Comment: Having said that, the fact has no "practical" consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important point is that $y$ should not clash with the free variables of $\mathscr{B}(x)$. Requiring $y$ to be the first variable in the sequence of all variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ that does not occur in $\mathscr{B}$ is just a definite way of ensuring that $y$ does not clash.

To see why this is necessary, take $\mathscr{B}(x) \equiv x > y$ so that, in $(\Bbb{Q}, >)$, for example, $(\exists_1 x) \mathscr{B}(x)$ is false.
Then if we allow $y$ in the definition to clash with the free variable $y$ of $\mathscr{B}(x)$, the definition would give us:

$$(\exists x)x > y \land (\forall x)(\forall y)(x > y \land y > y \to x = y)$$

which, unlike $(\exists_1 x) \mathscr{B}(x)$ is true, because $y > y$ is always false. If we avoid the clash, by picking a variable $z$ that is different from $x$ and $y$, we get the correct equivalent of $(\exists_1 x) \mathscr{B}(x)$:

$$(\exists x)x > y \land (\forall x)(\forall z)(x > y \land z > y \to x = z)$$

which is false, as we would expect.